# Toggle selected date jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

On the [example on jQuery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline), if you click on the same date you selected it doesn't unselect it.

Here's my code below to initialise my jQuery datepicker. I'm trying, in the `onSelect` method, to unselect the date if it was already selected.

```
var previousValue = null;
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
    dayNamesMin: ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"],
    duration: "slow",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    defaultDate: "1/12/2016",
    onSelect: function(date) {
        if (previousValue == $(this).val()) {

        }
        previousValue = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

But nothing I've tried is working. I've tried `setDate` and changing the date. But that just selects another date. I'm trying to untoggle the active `current-day`.

Comment: $.datepicker._clearDate(this); Is this worked for you ?

Comment: @Manish where do you get `clearDate` from? Is that a jQuery UI method? But nope, it doesn't work i'm afraid :( I've been trying to get this to work for around a day. I can't figure out how to.

Comment: Can you please share the working demo link where I can check ?

Comment: This looks like a reasonable feature request for me. Try raising one.

Comment: Hello again @TJ :) Yeah, is jQuery UI open-sourced in the sense. I could put a pull request in on git if I figured out how to do it?

Comment: @SmurfEkko https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', null);
```

This clears the currently selected date ([docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) but it also moves the calendar to the current month. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/gedkpgt5/

Comment: Thanks man! So I was using this, but yes, it resets it to the current date. Is there anyway to not do this and keep it on the current month instead?

Comment: @SmurfEkko There's to an open issue related to this: [datepicker('setDate' null) should not set today active](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8159)